# The solution of Cauchy problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $a,b\;\epsilon\;\mathbb{R}$ be such that $a^2+b^2\neq\;0$. Then the Cauchy problem
$a\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}+b\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=1$  ; $x,y\;\in\;\mathbb{R}$
$u(x,y)=x$ on $ax+by=1.$

1. has more than one solution if either $a$ or $b$ is zero
2. has no solution.
3. has a unique solution.
4. has infinitely many solution

**My attempt:**

Lagrange's auxiliary equations are $\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{du}{1}$ . Solving these and using the conditions we get the solution involving $u,x,y$. As all the variables are presents in the solution so the P.D.E. has **unique solution**. But this method is too lengthy and laborious. As in the problem it is mention that it is a Cauchy problem , so I think it can be solved using Cauchy problem. Here it is a linear Cauchy problem. I know to solve a Cauchy problem. But without solving how we can determine that the problem has unique solution ?

Please help...

Comment: i am new on pde

Answer (score 4):

As Herebrij and David pointed out; if one of the is zero, say $b=0$, then we have a unique solution.

Using Method of Characteristics, letting $x=x(t),y=y(t)$ and hence $u=u(t)$

$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$

Comparing to $a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$, we get

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=a,\frac{dy}{dt}=b, \frac{du}{dt}=1$$

$\frac{dx}{dt}=a\implies x=at\implies dt=\frac{dx}a$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=b\implies a\frac{dy}{dx}=b\implies ay-bx=y_0$

$\frac{du}{dt}=1\implies a\frac{du}{dx}=1\implies u(x,y)={x+F(y_0)\over a}={x+F(ay-bx)\over a}$

Now, $(\frac 1ax,0)$ lies on $ax+by=1$, so
$$u\left(\frac 1a x,0\right)=\frac 1a\left[\frac xa+F\left(-b\frac xa\right)\right]=\frac xa\implies F\left(-b\frac xa\right)=\frac xa\left[1-\frac 1a\right]$$

Letting $t=-b\frac xa$, we get
$$F(t)=\frac t{-b}\left[1-\frac 1a\right]$$

Substituting and simplifying, $u(x,y)=\frac{y(1-a)}{b}+x$

Which is unique for given $(a,b)$. Hence option 3.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't $\partial u(x,y) /\partial x=1$ and $\partial u(x,y) /\partial y=0$ leaving just $a=1$ and therefore $b = 0$ and $x=1$ for the remaining equations? Therefore we only have infinitely many solutions because $y$ can vary over all the reals.

Comment: but option 3 is correct

Comment: Well there is a unique solution in terms of a and b as far as I can see, but I can't see anything wrong with my answer besides that... is the expression definitely in terms of partial derivatives and not total derivatives?

Comment: $\frac{ \partial u}{\partial x} =1$, gives $u(x,y) = r(y) + x +c$. Then $1= u(1,y) = 1+r(y) +c$ for all $y$, and so $r(y) = -c$ for all $y$, only leaving $u(x,y) =x$ as solution.